# Run batch file with git pull in gitbash

Tags: git, batch-file, git-bash

I have a following problem. I want to write batch file and run this file everyday on vm.

I have a ssh key on vm so if I manually write "git pull" in gitbash I do not have to write password after that.

Now I want to write script in batch file which will do that automatically.

`c://TESTS/test/tes` - I want to pull only this one folder from repo.

I do not know how to create that kind of script. Any ideas?

Comment: is git in your PATH on the VM? If so, CD to your repository and run git pull

Comment: but if I call "git pull" by cmd it does not work. I want to do that from gitbash.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in gitbash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found solution in basic cmd:

```
cd c://TESTS/path
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
git pull 
pause
```

I missed a HOME variable. Now it is working without using git.exe or bash.exe.

Answer (score 4):

Since git is not in your PATH you need to add it in your batch script.

```
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\git
cd c://TESTS/test/tes
git pull
```

Comment: "path to git" is the path to bash.exe?

Comment: It's the place where you have git installed. Should be in the same directory as the git bash executable

Comment: @Sowiarz put `pause` at the end of the script

Comment: permission denied...fatal:Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Please make sure you have the corect acess rights and the repository exist.....but manually from git bash in folder it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61855/discussion-between-bartlomiej-lewandowski-and-sowiarz).

Answer (score 0):

If git is not added to your environment variable, follow below code block

```
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
git pull
```

If it is already added.

```
git pull
```

this is enough in your bat file. This file should be in your folder where you have checkout the files